# Get_object_or_None and prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-orm

```
curr = curr = get_object_or_None('Page', menu__slug=slug1, menu__parent__slug=slug2).prefetch_related('menu')
```

Need to use `prefetch_related` to get info from `ForeignKey` like an object and get `None` if it is not in table. Who knows, can I realize it by using `get_object_or_None`? It seems to work, but read, that it will not. Why so?

```
class Menu(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')
   slug = models.SlugField()
   region = models.ForeignKey()
   pos = models.IntegerField()
   on_top = models.BooleanField()
   nofollow = models.BooleanField()

class Page(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   name = models.CharField()
   menu = models.ForeignKey('Menu')
   meta_key = models.TextField()
   meta_desc = models.TextField()
   body = models.TextField()
   has_certificate = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_None()` is meant to be a shortcut to specifying a try except block, and it doesn't return a QuerySet, the class where `prefetch_related()` is from.

Also, if you're trying to get just one instance of your model you're not getting any performance enhancement by prefetching, in fact you'll make your query heavier on the db.